# How to set the response timeout of Web Service consumer in Mule 3?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I use HTTP listener and Web Consumer, there is no `http:request` in my case.
What should I do to increase the timeout of the WSC operation?

I only tried to set the global configuration of defaultResponseTimeout="600000".
But I want to know how to set the ResponseTimeout of one flow.

Answer (score 0):

To set HTTP configurations in a Web Service Consumer you reference an HTTP Request configuration using the `connectorConfig` attribute:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" responseTimeout="35000"/>
...
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration" wsdlLocation="myws.wsdl" service="MyWebServiceService" port="MyWebServicePort" serviceAddress="http://localhost:8081/"/>
```

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Set-timeout-for-WSConsumer-calls